# Adding text above page number on last page

Tags: page, lastpage, number

I am wondering how to add the text "[Last Page]" above the page number on the last page of my latex document?

Thanks.
Hannah

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, which document class are you using?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, it is difficult to do so using `fancy`. However, with a childlike thinking just for fun, I think that this may work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % For nice-looking document only
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-33]
\vfill
\centering [Last Page]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also do `\AtEndDocument{\par\vfill\centering [Last Page]}` in the document preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with headers/footers, you can use [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and condition on whether you're on `LastPage` or not. Based on this conditioning, you can set whatever you want in either case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage,fancyhdr,refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
      [Last page] \\
      \thepage
    \end{tabular}
  \else
    \thepage
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```